# Creating ShortCut in The HomeScreen

Tags: android, shortcut

I have an application that can perform various functions. I want to create a shortcut for a most frequently used function in my android phone homescreen.

Can anyone please tell me (with code and how the code actually work) how shortcut can be created? I have seen many lines of code but i can't understand. Please explain me.

I have used the following code=>Main problem is that shortcut is created in the home screen. But when i click on it an an Toast display Message like **"Application is not installed on your phone**".And in Log the error message is

*1)  WARN/ActivityManager(58): Permission 
denied: checkComponentPermission() reqUid=10046
2) WARN/ActivityManager(58): Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x10000000 cmp=a.a.a/.s bnds=[3,240][77,319] } from ProcessRecord{44f19b88 123:com.android.launcher/10025} (pid=123, uid=10025) requires null
3) ERROR/Launcher(123): Launcher does not have the permission to launch Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x10000000 cmp=a.a.a/.s bnds=[3,240][77,319] }. Make sure to create a MAIN intent-filter for the corresponding activity or use the exported attribute for this activity. tag=ShortcutInfo(title=Sukumar) intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x10000000 cmp=a.a.a/.s bnds=[3,240][77,319] }
4) ERROR/Launcher(123): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x10000000 cmp=a.a.a/.s bnds=[3,240][77,319] } from ProcessRecord{44f19b88 123:com.android.launcher/10025} (pid=123, uid=10025) requires null*

---

```
`package a.a.a;

 import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;

public class ShortActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Intent i=new Intent(this,s.class);
    Intent j=new Intent();
    j.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, i);
    j.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,"Sukumar");
    j.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON,R.drawable.icon);
    j.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    this.sendBroadcast(j);


}


}`
```

Answer (score 0):

To create the application shortcut on the Android Home screen, We just need to fire a simple Intent with the action `com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT`. Name and icon of the shortcut, we can put the with the exrta parameters of the Intent.
Check the method below :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, intentActivity);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, textShortcut);
Parcelable iconResource = (Parcelable) bitmap;
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, iconResource);
intent.putExtra("duplicate", duplicateNeed); // (duplicateNeed=false)
// will not allow the
// duplicate same name
// shortcuts.
intent.setAction(INSTALL_SHORTCUT_ACTION);
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```